# Getting VBA to click a button on an addin toolbar... CommandBars?

Tags: vba, excel

I have live data that needs to be updated every hour in excel, fed through the Reuters addin. This would usually be automatic but because I am feeding through a different kind of data, it will only be refreshed if you manually click the "Refresh" button. Therefore, unless I can find a way of getting my VBA to click this button once an hour, my entire model is useless...haha!

I have been reading that such a task may be possible through commandBars but in all honesty I am struggling to make sense of the examples that are online.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can try this piece of code. You can run a scheduler which will run a macro to initiate the macro you need within fixed intervals.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Do While TimeValue(Now) < "23:59:59"
    ' Enter the name of the Macro that you want to run in the NAME OF MACRO field
     Application.OnTime TimeValue(Now), "NAME OF MACRO"

     newHour = Hour(Now())
     newMinute = Minute(Now()) + 10
     newSecond = Second(Now())
     waitTime = TimeSerial(newHour, newMinute, newSecond)
     'Waits for 10 minutes
     Application.Wait waitTime
Loop

End Sub
```

Run this macro in the Workbook Open Event. The fastest way to get to the Private Module of the Workbook Object (ThisWorkbook) is to right click on the Excel icon next to "File" and select "View Code". I have scheduled it to 10 mins. You can change it according to the frequency you need.

This code however has it's limitations. You will have to leave the excel open all the time. And furthermore you will not be able to run any other macro at all. If this is something that needs to be run throughout the day, I suggest you run this excel in a dedicated system, else we will have to change the code as per your specific requirement.

Hope this solution helps you! Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: `OnTime` is a good option, but it isn't properly implemented, see http://www.cpearson.com/excel/OnTime.aspx . Using `Application.Wait` will keep Excel stuck in VBA.